# Core Data Earthquakes Demo crashed in Preview

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

currently I learn more about Core Data and testet the Apple's provided Demo Code "Earthquakes - Loading and Display a large Data Feed". But now I encountered a problem with Canvas View. Everytime the Editor crashed when I use the provided Quake.preview.

I also tried to read the crashLogs but I don't know what causes this error. In ContentView, when I change the provider from .preview to .shared, it didn't crash.

Has anybody an idea why this happens? Thank You

The ContentView PreviewProvider:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let quakesProvider = QuakesProvider.preview
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(quakesProvider: quakesProvider)
        
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext,
                          quakesProvider.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

```
    /// An earthquake for use with canvas previews.
    static var preview: Quake {
        let quakes = Quake.makePreviews(count: 1)
        return quakes[0]
    }

   
    static func makePreviews(count: Int) -> [Quake] {
        var quakes: [Quake] = []
        let viewContext = QuakesProvider.preview.container.viewContext
        for index in 0..<count {
            let quake = Quake(context: viewContext)
            quake.code = UUID().uuidString
            quake.time = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(index) * -300)
            quake.magnitude = .random(in: -1.1...10.0)
            quake.place = "15km SSW of Cupertino, CA"
            quakes.append(quake)
        }
        return quakes
    }
```

```
    /// A quakes provider for use with canvas previews.
    static let preview: QuakesProvider = {
        let provider = QuakesProvider(inMemory: true)
        Quake.makePreviews(count: 10)
        return provider
    }()
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing, the crash appears to be happening at this line: `let viewContext = QuakesProvider.preview.container.viewContext`. Not sure what causes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a circular dependency between

`static let preview: QuakesProvider` calling `Quake.makePreviews(count: 10)`

and

`static func makePreviews(count: Int) -> [Quake]` calling `QuakesProvider.preview`

You can change to:

```
static func makePreviews(context: NSManagedObjectContext, count: Int) -> [Quake] {
    var quakes: [Quake] = []
    for index in 0..<count {
        let quake = Quake(context: context)
        quake.code = UUID().uuidString
        quake.time = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(index) * -300)
        quake.magnitude = .random(in: -1.1...10.0)
        quake.place = "15km SSW of Cupertino, CA"
        quakes.append(quake)
    }
    return quakes
}

/// A quakes provider for use with canvas previews.
static let preview: QuakesProvider = {
    let provider = QuakesProvider(inMemory: true)
    Quake.makePreviews(context: provider.container.viewContext, count: 10)
    return provider
}()

/// An earthquake for use with canvas previews.
static var preview: Quake {
    let provider = QuakesProvider(inMemory: true)
    let quakes = Quake.makePreviews(context: provider.container.viewContext, count: 1)
    return quakes[0]
}
```

Also in `QuakesProvider.swift` remove the `private` access level for the initializer so we can use it in the `Quake` extension:

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) { ... }
```

**SwiftUI previews:**

For a `List` or any views where you have a `FetchRequest` on a `Quake` entity:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    // Use the in-memory and pre-populated QuakesProvider
    static let quakesProvider = QuakesProvider.preview
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(quakesProvider: quakesProvider)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, quakesProvider.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

For the single item in `QuakeRow`:

```
struct QuakeRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Use the in-memory QuakesProvider to create only 1 item, and returns it
        QuakeRow(quake: .preview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Solved my problem(s) and am amazed that it doesn't already have a million upvotes.